# Aptitude keeps saying package installed when it was removed and purged

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

I have a server, 8.04, which i've been toying with Postfix, installing and removing with purge option. The thing is, i wanna reinstall it (so it shows the config menu) but Aptitude and apt keep telling that it's already installed.

I removed and purged several times, even manually deleted some files the purge left, and no luck.

So, is there a way to manually remove the entry or something else, so Aptitude installs it normally?

Thanks!!

Comment: It would be helpful if you post the output from the aptitude purge command, and "dpkg -l postfix".

Comment: Please change the title to something more meaningful.

Comment: Done, hope you like it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning: Do not try this unless you have exhausted all other avenues.**

Since apt-get, aptitude etc all internally use the dpkg command, we are going to remove all traces of the package installation from the dpkg database, and con dpkg, apt-get, aptitude etc into thinking the package was never installed.

- The dpkg database is the **/var/lib/dpkg/status** file. **Take a backup of this file.** We are going to be messing about with the guts of the dpkg system, and you need the original file in case this procedure goes belly up.
- Edit the status file:

  > sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
- Locate the entry for the *postfix* package in this file. Each package will typically have an entry like shown below. Delete the whole entry. ***Note:*** There should be no packages that depend on this package. If there are, you should remove those packages first, so when you open this file, the package is referenced in only one block, which you will then proceed to remove.

  > Package: autokey 
  >   Status: install ok installed 
  >   Priority: optional 
  >   Section: kde 
  >   Installed-Size: 456 
  >   Maintainer: Chris Dekter  
  >   Architecture: all 
  >   Version: 0.60.4-0~jaunty 
  >   Depends: python (>= 2.6), python-central (>= 0.6.11), python-kde4, python-qt4, python-qscintilla2, python-xlib 
  >   Conffiles: 
  >   /etc/init.d/autokey 1f0e894e58a6ff428e3a892c27caf300 
  >   Description: Desktop automation utility 
  >   AutoKey is a desktop automation utility for Linux and X11. It allows the 
  >   automation of virtually any task by responding to typed abbreviations and 
  >   hotkeys. It offers a full-featured GUI that makes it highly accessible for 
  >   novices, as well as a scripting interface offering the full flexibility and 
  >   power of the Python language. 
  >   Homepage: http://autokey.googlecode.com/ 
  >   Python-Version: >= 2.6
- Save the file.
- **Reboot.**  There may be cached versions of the file, so a reboot is necessary to ensure everyone reads from this new file.
- Re-install the package.

The only reason I post these instructions is that I had a similar issue recently: The autokey package was in a horribly messed up state (the disk got full in the middle of an install, and entries that should have been written were not), and I finally had to resort to the above steps to reinstall the package. **It worked for me, and it should work for you, but you use these instructions at your own risk.**

**Edit:** I should also let you know I used apt-get for the (failed) install and the re-install.

Comment: Worked. I deleted the entry regardless some calls from other packages. I'll see how this action's repercussion, but managed to install it back!

Answer (score 0):

Your package is in an inconsistent state. You may need to reinstall it (aptitude install postfix). And possibly reconfigure it (dpkg-reconfigure postfix).

Comment: This did not work, that was the whole point of this topic. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You claim to have used both `Aptitude` and `apt`, I'm just hoping you haven't tried to install with `Aptitude` and remove with `apt` or vice versa, because that's a big no no. You can try

```
aptitude hold postfix
```

which should fix the package in it's current state. Then try a purge. Alternatively try to install over it:

```
aptitude install postfix
```

then purge.

Comment: Why is that a no-no? They both use the same database, and probably share a substantial amount of code.

Comment: It mostly has to do with removing packages, there is frequently differences between what each package manager views as "orphaned dependencies".

Comment: Please check the output when trying to install postfix, after doing the hold thingie:

http://pastebin.com/f69695192